# Deepin 15.9 stuck in boot up

Tags: linux, grub

I don't know why but I can seem to get over this screen in deepin 15.9.
I´m running windows at this moment.

[image]

Pc Specs:

`Intel Core i7-7700HQ @ 2.80GHz 2.81GHz` |
`16G RAM` |
`64-BIT operating system` |
`Intel(R) HD Graphics 630` |
`NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti` |

Distros installed:

Tried to install manjaro but it was always giving a `watchdog CPU#0` (It was something like that)

Tried deepin but it got stuck in loading screen after login! I installed deepin using a USB drive with the software Rufus in DD mode!

Installed Linux Mint and it went first try!

Comment: Hi and welcome. I don't know either and you'd needs psychic powers - only available in fiction or delusional minds - to actually know why it's stuck there. Try pressing ESC to see if some text shows up and then [edit] and update your question with it.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia haha ok I will try that and i will come back in a sec

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia After 10 tries to load deepin your answer and it works!

Comment: Nice :) But it wasn't an answer and the suggestion wasn't a fix either, it was just to try to gather some information. But if it works now, excellent. Install all the pending updates and hopefully it won't happen again.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I tried to etc but it didn't do anything and I tried to start it again and it got stuck again! I updated grub also and I don't know if that made any changes, and when i started i did apt-get update and upgrade!

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  You took the time to update your question, but it still doesn't contain any information that would be helpful in solving your problem.  There are endless potential issues that could cause this symptom.  The fact that it happens with both 15.8 and 15.9 makes it less likely that you downloaded a defective distro.  As a test, I would try installing Linux Mint.  It comes pretty well loaded with drivers, and tends not to have a lot of installation issues.  If that installs and works, it would at least be a benchmark for comparison.  (cont'd)

Comment: Also, provide information about your system.  What is the model, and if it offers options, describe its hardware complement.  What OS did it come loaded with?  Is this your first attempt at installing any Linux distro on it?  Give is some history on the machine and any problems or related experience (like did you previously install a Linux distro that worked?).  At what point in the boot does that splash screen appear?  If this is not an ancient machine, how are you handling UEFI?

Comment: @fixer1234 I add some more info and i´m going to try to load mint !

Comment: @fixer1234 loaded mint first try no errors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than investing the time to figure out what's going wrong with Deepin, let me suggest another way to get there, which will also give you a more stable platform.  This is based on the fact that Mint installed and worked on your system without a hitch.

**Alternate Approach**

Distros aren't as different as they may seem, especially within a family, like Debian-based ones.  The main thing that makes them seem different is the desktop environment and its customization.  They also often ship with a different collection of utilities and applications, but those are easy to mix and match regardless of the distro.  If you want a particular desktop environment, you can usually install it on a distro of choice.

The Deepin distro core is based on Debian's Unstable branch, with the Deepin desktop environment (and a bundle of utilities and applications).  As the name implies, Debian's Unstable branch is where things start out when they have an expectation of potential problems (or at least no expectation that they will be relatively bug-free).  They graduate from there to the Debian Testing branch, which still isn't proven bug-free enough for Debian to include in it's Stable distro (which is actually the only official Debian release).

So the degree of problems you encounter depends heavily on the extent of testing performed by the Deepin developers.  As I'll describe below, they rely, to some extent, on a rolling release to fix bugs as they are discovered.    If you are proficient in Linux and don't mind getting your hands dirty working under the hood solving issues, this might not be a problem for you.

Ubuntu (on which Mint is based), is also based on Debian's Unstable branch, but it goes through extensive testing and interim releases before being incorporated into the stable LTS (Long Term Support) release.  The LTS releases rarely have critical problems.  Mint is basically the Ubuntu LTS release with some customization and additional utilities.

Besides potential branch-based problems, there may also be a driver issue underlying your problem.  The fact that Mint works for you (it comes with a pretty complete set of drivers), addresses both of those potential issues.

Deepin relies on Qt, which isn't trivial to integrate into a distro.  Mint stopped supporting KDE (which is also Qt-based), because it was taking too much resources to integrate Qt with the Ubuntu base of Mint.  However, there is still a collection of developers integrating Qt with Ubuntu; they are doing it to support KDE (the Kubuntu project).  So if you really want to use Deepin, I would go the following route.

Install Kubuntu, which will get you a distro based on Ubuntu's LTS release, with Qt already well integrated.  Then add the Deepin desktop environment.

**How To**

I haven't personally done it, but here's a [link to how to do it](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/06/how-to-install-deepin-desktop-environment-on-ubuntu-18-04).  I encourage you to read the article for all of the details and discussion, but here's the gist:

- Add the Deepin desktop PPA for Ubuntu to your system sources:

  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leaeasy/dde
- Install the meta-package:

  sudo apt install dde dde-file-manager
- Ubuntu will download, unpack and install the core Deepin desktop packages and dependencies on your system.  Note that the meta-package supposedly includes all of the Qt stuff needed, but I would still trust Kubuntu more as a starting point.  Anything already there via Kubuntu won't be duplicated by the package manager.
- During the installation process you will be prompted to choose which display manager (aka login screen) you want to use.  Deepin relies on LightDM to power its login and lock/unlock screens (“Deepin Greeter”) but you can (and the link recommends) opt to keep the default as `GDM` (on Kubuntu, it might be `KDM`).
- Once the whole install process is complete, log out of your current desktop session.  From the login screen select the “Deepin” session.
- You should be greeted by a Deepin splash screen. Click “ok” to be taken the desktop upon which you’ll see … a dock, and nothing else.
- Click the Settings icon in the dock to open the Control Center.  From here you can browse through your various system settings, change theme, try a different icon theme, and so on.
- Click the “Launcher” button (the furthest left) to open the app launcher. The Deepin launcher is full-screen by default and its icons are tiny. You can hold Ctrl and tap the + button to increase the size or, to shrink the launch down, click the expansion icon in the upper right corner.

  You’ll notice that Deepin apps look great, but regular Ubuntu ones less so. To make GTK apps “look” the part in Deepin you’ll need to install the Deepin GTK theme:

  sudo apt install deepin-gtk-theme
- Once the Deepin GTK theme has been installed, just open the  Deepin Control Center and head to `Personalisation > Window Theme > Deepin/Deepin Dark` to apply it.

**Rolling vs. LTS Release**

Note one difference in doing it this way is the update scheme.  Deepin is a rolling release, which can be both a blessing and a curse.  If you are conscientious about installing the updates, it can keep things very current.

Based on an unstable branch, that will load fixes sooner, but it can also load new things that haven't been adequately tested.  There's a higher risk of an update leading to problems.

Also, rolling releases generally can handle updates for only a limited time period.  If you get too far behind in installing updates, it may be unable to go from your current status to the latest versions of everything, or could introduce incompatibilities.

Rolling releases are generally better for users with enough Linux proficiency to be able to recover from problems if they occur.

Kubuntu is based on an Ubuntu LTS release.  This is a release that has already gone through extensive testing, both internally and by users via Ubuntu interim releases.

Apps and utilities will get updates as they become available and are tested.  But the core of Ubuntu is supported for five years.  It gets security updates and bug fixes, but generally not fundamental changes to the Ubuntu base.  This keeps it stable and minimizes problems.

The elements that don't change are mostly things that you are typically unaware of or that don't much affect your routine usage.  So there isn't usually a need to upgrade to a newer release during its lifetime unless some new OS capabilities are important to you.  With Ubuntu, you can usually upgrade to a new release if you want to without having to start over and reinstall everything.

Comment: Does Ubuntu have all drivers because I can install mint but I can't seem to be able to install ubuntu I gets stuck after login!

Comment: @DeadSec, strange.  Ubuntu is also pretty good with supplied drivers, but it's possible that Mint's is even more complete.  Most of the differences between Mint and Ubuntu are utilities and customization that Mint adds.  Under the hood it's still essentially Ubuntu.  Some of Mint's utilities are really good, though, so I like it better than Ubuntu.  Since you had good luck with Mint, start there.  A safe bet for your "base"would be Mint Mate, which is a good, Windows-like UI that isn't excessively large and has decent utilities.  (cont'd)

Comment: You should be able to follow the same instructions in the answer to add the Deepin DE.  Hopefully, it will contain all of the Qt components you need (people have reported success with that procedure).  If by chance, you run into any Qt issues, I can share instructions for loading KDE on Mint from Kubuntu (which I've successfully done), which includes all of Kubuntu's Qt integration.  Then you could load Deepin on that.  KDE is pretty big, though, so if your goal is just Deepin, try the procedure without the KDE step first.

Comment: I think what was causing the problem was the lack of nvidea drivers in ubunto because i sucessfuly installed mint and it came with the needed drivers! Thanks for all your help!